# Are there any morpheme dictionaries for Russian?

Tags: морфология, суффиксы, resources

Is there such thing as morpheme dictionary, where one could look up functions and meanings of prefixes, suffixes, particles, etc. ?

In particular, I was interested in the range of meanings that prefix "рас-\раз-" have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Кузнецова А. И., Ефремова Т. Ф. Словарь морфем русского языка. — М., 1986
- Ефремова Т. Ф. Новый словарь русского языка. Толково-словообразовательный. — М.: Русский язык, 2000.

Comment: Thanks. Are there online version (so that you know)?

Comment: @Olga http://www.efremova.info/